# Displaying 2 custom Data attribute items within a div. Ex: Currency & Amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an E-Commerce website built on HTML, JavaScript & PHP.

On product details page user can add product to cart thus I'm displaying total amount of cart value.

I want to display decimal number always (10,2) format.

Currently my code works with minimal thing. On clicking "Add to cart" if product price is 12.00 the Counter div displays 12 only.

```html
<span>
<a href="cart.php" class="text-white">
<i  class="fa fa-shopping-cart p1"  data-count="10" data-currency="&euro;" id="total"></i>
</a>
</span>
```

```css
 .p1[data-count]:after{
  position:absolute;
  right:1%;
  top:1%;
  content: attr(data-count);
  font-size:10px;
  padding:.2em;
  line-height:1em;
  color: white;
  background:#21468b;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

```
<script>
var theTotal = '0';
var ProductSellingPrice = '12.00'

$('#insert').click(function(){

   theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number(ProductSellingPrice);

    $('#total').attr('data-count', theTotal);

});


</script>
```

So on clicking insert, the existing TheTotal & current product Price gets added. If there are no products on cart then p1 doesn't display any value, thus want to display zero always if empty/zero. If product price is 12.00 then shows 12 only. If product price is 12.50 then 12.50 is displayed.

I want it to display decimal always & also currency symbol using data attribute.

Displaying decimal problem is solved by @Simone, i m not able to find answer for displaying currency before value using data attribute.

Comment: From the code I can't see why it should show decimals for integer values at all. Can you stripe the dynamic values so we can test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 12.00 and not 12 you have to use [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

So you have to convert all the single product total (quantity * price is the single total ) into Float number and when you do the total sum, take the number and do this:

```
Number.parseFloat(total).toFixed(2); // two decimal
```

Example:

```
var quantity = 10;
var price = 11;
var tot = parseFloat(quantity * price).toFixed(2);
console.log(tot); // "110.00"
```

Comment: I did this:    theTotal =     Number.parseFloat(theTotal).toFixed(2) +  Number.parseFloat(ProductSellingPrice).toFixed(2);

on clicking insert i get as : NaN11.00

Comment: Could you tell me how i should use this : Number.parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);

Comment: I add an example on my answer. You call the toFixed(2) at the end of the calculation, because it will return a string.

Comment: awesome. What about currency symbol b4 the value?